# Why it shows not a single-group function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the number of countries of region 2, the name of the first country and the number
of locations of countries in region 2.

Like this it shows not a single-group function. Do you know why it shows this error and how to properly solve it?

```
select country_id, count(*),
        (select country_name from hr.countries order by country_name ASC fetch first row only) as number_countries ,
        (select count(*) from hr.locations where country_id = country_id) 
        
from hr.countries where region_id = 2;
```

Comment: Your query doesn't look like it would do anything useful even if the syntax errors were fixed.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS, because the DBMS differ concerning the SQL features they support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is invalid, because you aggregate your rows to one result row, but tell the DBMS to show *the* country_id. Which?

As to the query: Just join the tables and count:

```
select
  min(country_id),
  count(distinct country_id) as country_count,
  count(*) as location_count
from hr.countries c
join hr.locations l using (country_id)
where c.region_id = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks but also without the country_id like "select count(*),
        (select country_name from hr.countries order by country_name ASC fetch first row only) as number_countries ,
        (select count(*) from hr.locations where country_id = country_id) 
        
from hr.countries where region_id = 2;" shows the same error.

Comment: With your solution it seems that the output is not showing properly, for example it appears the country_id 'BR' but the first country should be "AR". The output is to show  
the number of countries of that region 2, the name of the first country and the number of locations from countries of region 2.

Comment: Your first comment: Correct, because the second subquery gets one value per country. You'd have to add these up: `sum((select count(*) from hr.locations ...))`.

Comment: Your second comment: I am sure you are mistaken. The `WHERE` clause limits the rows to get only region 2. The join of countries and locations is on `country_id`, so how could `count(distinct country_id)` not get the country count in region 2? And how would `count(*)` not count its locations? `MIN(country_id)` gets the first country ordered by ID. If there are two IDs 'AR' and 'BR' for the region, you'll get 'AR', because this comes first in the alphabet. `MIN(country_id)` doesn't consider the country name, though.

Comment: You still haven't told us your DBMS. Which are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? PostgreSQL? ...

Comment: Thanks! Im testing on oracle.

Comment: Then, if you rather want the `country_id` for the first `country_name` in the alphabet, use `min(country_id) keep (dense_rank first order by country_name)`. And if you just want the `country_name` itself, then `min(country_name)` of course.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt show the correct output. It only shows one country but it should show 5 because there are 5 countries in region 2.

Comment: Here is a db fidlle showing that the query is correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d13b46bee910d55a9801c37971d9ed4b

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a non-aggregated column in select without having it in group by. For instance, you have a non-aggregated column country_id in your select ( meaning you are not using any aggregate function on this column like sum, max, min etc) so you have to use

```
Group by country_id
```

In your case -

```
select country_id, count(*),
        (select country_name from hr.countries order by country_name 
ASC fetch first row only) as number_countries ,
        (select count(*) from hr.locations where country_id = country_id) 
from hr.countries where region_id = 2
group by country_id;
```

Otherwise it will fail. The other option would be to remove the non-aggregated column - in your case country_id from select and just keep the ones with aggregate function.

Comment: Thanks but like that it shows always that the count is 1. And for example the there are  5 countries in region 2.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the number of countries of region 2, the name of the first country and the number of locations of countries in region 2.

My best guess for this query is:

```
select (select count(*) from hr.countries where region_id = 2) as number_countries,
       (select min(country_name) from hr.countries) as first_contry,
       (select count(*)
        from hr.locations l join
             hr.countries c
             on l.country_id = c.country_id
        where c.region_id = 2
       ) as num_locations
```

Comment: Thanks like that it shows from keyword not found where expected.

Comment: @Jack . . . You need to tag your question with the database you are using.